# for loop does not loop the code multiple times JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am making a battleship game.. and a piece of code needs to place random battleships on the field for the enemy. (5 battleships so i now need to call the function 5 times). But the first for loop is kind of doing nothing. why, and how can i maybe fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
var ships = [
        {
            shipClass: "cruiser",
            shipLength: 3
        },
        {
            shipClass: "battleship",
            shipLength: 4
        },
        {
            shipClass: "submarine",
            shipLength: 3
        },
        {
            shipClass: "destroyer",
            shipLength: 2
        },
        {
            shipClass: "carrier",
            shipLength: 5
        },
    ]
    var currentShipIndex = 0

    function placeEnemyBoat() {
        var currentShipSize = ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength
        var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * numRows * numRows)

        for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++){
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                if (isValidEnemyPosition(randomInt, ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength, "vertical")) {
                    for (var idx = randomInt; idx < randomInt + currentShipSize; idx++) {
                        enemySquares[idx].draw(enemyCtx, "ship", ships[currentShipIndex].shipClass)
                    }
                    currentShipIndex += 1
                }
            }else {
                if (isValidEnemyPosition(randomInt, ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength, "horizontal")) {
                    for (var index = randomInt; index < randomInt + (currentShipSize * numRows); index += numRows) {
                        enemySquares[index].draw(enemyCtx, "ship", ships[currentShipIndex].shipClass)
                    }
                    currentShipIndex += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have numRows, draw, enemyCtx, enemySquares, etc. are defined elsewhere in your code.  Without more of your code, it's really hard to say.

I commented out a line above the for loop and most of the for loop's body to avoid these undeclared variables.  And I added a simple console.log statement.

```
var ships = [
    {
        shipClass: "cruiser",
        shipLength: 3
    },
    {
        shipClass: "battleship",
        shipLength: 4
    },
    {
        shipClass: "submarine",
        shipLength: 3
    },
    {
        shipClass: "destroyer",
        shipLength: 2
    },
    {
        shipClass: "carrier",
        shipLength: 5
    },
]
var currentShipIndex = 0

function placeEnemyBoat() {
    var currentShipSize = ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength
    //var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * numRows * numRows)

    for (var i = 0; i < ships.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        /*
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            if (isValidEnemyPosition(randomInt, ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength, "vertical")) {
                for (var idx = randomInt; idx < randomInt + currentShipSize; idx++) {
                    enemySquares[idx].draw(enemyCtx, "ship", ships[currentShipIndex].shipClass)
                }
                currentShipIndex += 1
            }
        }else {
            if (isValidEnemyPosition(randomInt, ships[currentShipIndex].shipLength, "horizontal")) {
                for (var index = randomInt; index < randomInt + (currentShipSize * numRows); index += numRows) {
                    enemySquares[index].draw(enemyCtx, "ship", ships[currentShipIndex].shipClass)
                }
                currentShipIndex += 1
            }
        }
        */
    }
}

placeEnemyBoat();
```

But what you have does seem to be making five iterations through the for loop.